# Expected Values of an Indicator Variable

Tags: expected-value

I want to calculate the expected value of an indicator variable. The problem is of the form:
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbf{1}[f(x_{a})>f(x_{b})]\right)$$
 where $f(\cdot)$
  is some function. I have no idea to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: An indicator function = 1 if its argument is true, and = 0 if its argument if false. So what is the expected value of an indicator function?

Comment: +1 @MarkL.Stone Yes, thinking about what the indicator function is doing is the key here. [It might help initially to think of an indicator over a discrete variable.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) has a very simple formula for the expected value of an indicator function.  But applied to your problem,

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbf{1}[f(x_{a})>f(x_{b})]\right)=\int\mathbf{1}[f(x_{a})>f(x_{b})]d\mathbb{P}=Pr(f(x_{a})>f(x_{b}))$$

Comment: I had a professor who called this the ["fundamental bridge" of probability](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/cs50-probability/fundamentalbridge.php).

Comment: That link in unavailable

Answer (score 2):

I think I can answer my question after giving it some thought. It should be:$$\mathbb{E}\mathbf{1}[(f(x_{a})>f(x_{b})]=[1\mathbf{Pr}(f(x_{a})>f(x_{b})+0\mathbf{Pr}(f(x_{a})\leq f(x_{b})]=\mathbf{Pr}(f(x_{a})>f(x_{b})]$$